# How can I check if the file uploaded to the server is blank using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have built a react application and have created Fileupload module to upload the YAML files from the local to the server.

Can anyone help me in implementing the check so that if a user uploads an Empty file then they should be alerted('Empty File uploaded').

Putting the reproducible part of my client and server side here where I have handled the syntax of the file and checked each line for a comment and tried implementing the blank file validation but it didn't work. Can anyone please help in the following.

Client side

````
handleUpload = async (e) => {
    console.log("Starting upload");
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", this.state.file);

    try {
      const res = await axios.post(this.props.url + "/upload", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });

      const { status } = res.data;
      if (status === "ok") {
        alert("File Uploaded Successfully");
        this.setState({ file: "" });
        this.setState({ fileName: "Choose File" });
        document.getElementById("closeButton").click();
      } 
      else if (status === "invalid") {
        const { error } = res.data
        // console.log(error.message)
        var errmsg= "Invalid Syntax!!"+ error.message
        alert(errmsg);
      }
      else if (status === "Invalid File") {
        alert("Invalid File");
        this.setState({ file: "" });
        this.setState({ fileName: "Choose File" });
        document.getEementById("closeButton").click();
      }
      else if (status === "Blank") {
        alert("Error!!");
        this.setState({ file: "" });
        this.setState({ fileName: "Choose File" });
        document.getEementById("closeButton").click();
      }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.response.data.msg); 
    }
  };
```
````

Answer (score 0):

you could use the filereader API like this to get the content and perform validation (like a regex validation, to check if it's empty) the one I did here is just a simple example, not the best one at all but you get the idea.

```
var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function(e) { 
          var contents = e.target.result;
              if(contents.trim().length === 0) {
                   console.log('empty file');
              } else { // upload file }
        );  
      }
      r.readAsText(f)
```

Hope it helps you, have a nice day !